# Понедельничный, вторничный, сред...?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, орфоэпия

Существуют ли "правильные" прилагательные производные от слов "среда" и "четверг"?

Comment: "средный", кажется, звучит наименее плохо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Здесь](http://fictionbook.ru/pages/download_prew/?file=8906306)<sup>1</sup> на стр. 20-21 представлены результаты поиска в 4 основных толковых словарях (Большой и Малый академические, четырёхтомный Толковый Ушакова и словарь Ожегова).

Во всех четырёх есть *субботний, воскресный* и *вторничный*; в трёх есть *понедельничный* и *пятничный*; в двух - *четверговый*; ни в одном из четырёх нет прилагательного *средовый*.

От себя добавлю, что "*четверговый*" используется в понятии "четверговая соль", а "*средовый*" можно встретить разве что в литературном переводе одного из произведений Станислава Лема по специфическому поводу (столкновение всех этих прилагательных).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Б.Ю. Норман, Когнитивный синтаксис руссого языка, учебное пособие.</sub>

Comment: *ни в одном из четырёх нет прилагательного средовый* - а средовой? или середовый? Именно эти формы обычно приводятся как "заменители". И я согласен, что скорее уж они, чем "средовый" - это вообще ни в какие ворота не лезет. А мне ближе "ср**е**динный" - но его найти трудно в силу омографии.

Comment: Первые два мне кажутся ещё менее естественными; слово "срединный" родственно середине и у него есть своё применение. Я бы предложил "средничный" (среда-средница, что будет пусть приснится).

Comment: *слово "срединный" родственно середине и у него есть своё применение* - а я ударение зачем ставил?))) А то, что среда само по себе родственно середине, это никто под сомнение не ставит.

Comment: В отношении "первых двух". К сожаления или к счастью, средов**о**й довольно прочно вошло в профессиональных жаргон всякого рода экологов и контролеров за ними. А середовый якобы дает Даль (правда не совсем понятно в каком значении). И то и другое легко ищется гуглом. Не в "промышленных масштабах", но все-таки.

Answer (score 5):

> Существуют ли "правильные" прилагательные производные от слов "среда"
>   и "четверг"?

Из книги Бориса Нормана "Русский язык в задачах и ответах" (М., 2011):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Есть только четверговый, вполне распространено.

Слово среда ни в одном значении прилагательного не имеет, но самое близкое, что можно предположить - ср**е**динный, в разговорное речи, пожалуй, возможно.
Средовый - плохо, это продуктивная форма только от основ мужского рода, а тут надо что-то по образцу "пятничный", "субботний"...

А вопрос - хороший, спасибо.

(+)

Еще встречается "средов**о**й" - главным образом в отношении окружающей среды. Вряд ли нормативно.
И дают еще "серед**о**вый" - со сслылкой на Даля, сам не видел. Тоже сомнительной нормативности.

Answer (score 1):

Средовый и четверговый. Другое дело, что они не так часто используются.

Answer (score 0):

Прилагательное от четверга - "четверговый".
Среда имеет значение среднего дня недели. Поэтому, по логике, прилагательное от него - "средний". Другое дело, что в контексте, например "среднее мероприятие" оно будет восприниматься скорее как характеризующее мероприятие, а не время его проведения. Потому лучше заменить на "среди недельное мероприятие" или на причастный оборот "проводимое в среду мероприятие".